# Using SetImage inside a threadjob

Tags: powershell

I have a function that inserts pictures into a PPT and involves the code:

```
$file = get-item($pic);
$img = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($file);



[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($img);


$slide = $pp1.Slides.Item($targetslide)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$shape = $Slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial($ppPasteJPG,$false,$null,$null,$null,$null)
```

However, I created a function that uses this function and put that inside the action script of a threadjob. Now when it is activated it yields the error:

```
Exception calling "SetImage" with "1" argument(s): "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it."
At C:\...\PicInsertPPT.ps1:17 char:1
+ [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($img);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ThreadStateException
```

What can I replace that line with that will work as one task in a threadjob with multiple parallel tasks?

I am thinking of trying to apply:

```
CommandBars.ExecuteMso("PictureInsertFromFile")
```

But I am not entirely sure how to control what picture is inserted that way.

Edit: my threadjob code is:

```
Function ThreadMaster{



param ($folder)




$global:folder = $folder



  # Use the system's temp folder in this example.
  $global:dir = $folder

  # Define the tasks as an array of custom objects that specify the dir.
  # and file name pattern to monitor as well as the action script block to 
  # handle the events.
  $tasks = # array of custom objects to describe the 
    [pscustomobject] @{
      DirToMonitor = $dir
      FileNamePattern = '*.csv'
      Action = {
        $path = $EventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $EventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $EventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $EventArgs.TimeGenerated




         Write-Host -NoNewLine "`nINFO: Event 1 raised:`n$($EventArgs | Format-List | Out-String)"



        Import-Module C:\...Report1V1.ps1


       $Actionpath = Split-Path $Path



        write-host $Actionpath " Ready for Report1"



       Report1 $Actionpath

       write-host $Actionpath "Report1 Generated"



        "`nEvent 1 output: " + $EventArgs.Fullpath

}
      }
    },
    [pscustomobject] @{
      DirToMonitor = $dir
      FileNamePattern = '*4.4_10X*'
      Action = {
        $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
        $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
        $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

        Write-Host -NoNewLine "`nINFO: Event 2 raised:`n$($EventArgs | Format-List | Out-String)"


        Import-Module C:\...\Report2V1.ps1





      $Actionpath = Split-Path $Path




      $Actionpath = Split-Path $Actionpath








      write-host $Actionpath " Ready for Report2"



      Report2 $Actionpath


      write-host "Report2 Generated" 



        "`nEvent 2 output: " + $EventArgs.Fullpath


      }  
    } 
}
  # Start a separate thread job for each action task.
  $threadJobs = $tasks | ForEach-Object {

    Start-ThreadJob -ArgumentList $_ {

      param([pscustomobject] $task)

      # Create and initialize a thread-specific watcher.
      # Note: To keep system load low, it's generally better to use a *shared* 
      #       watcher, if feasible. You can define it in the caller's scope
      #       and access here via $using:watcher
      $watcher = [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher] [ordered] @{
        Path   = $task.DirToMonitor
        Filter = $task.FileNamePattern
        IncludeSubdirectories = $true
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true # start watching.
        InternalBufferSize = 65536
      }

      # Subscribe to the watcher's Created events, which returns an event job.
      # This indefinitely running job receives the output from the -Action script
      # block whenever the latter is called after an event fires.
      $eventJob = Register-ObjectEvent -ea stop $watcher Created -Action $task.Action

      Write-Host "`nINFO: Watching $($task.DirToMonitor) for creation of $($task.FileNamePattern) files..."

      # Indefinitely wait for output from the action blocks and relay it.
      try {
        while ($true) {
          Receive-Job $eventJob
          Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500  # sleep a little
        }
      }
      finally { 
         # !! This doesn't print, presumably because this is killed by the
         # !! *caller* being killed, which then doesn't relay the output anymore.
        Write-Host "Cleaning up thread for task $($task.FileNamePattern)..."
        # Dispose of the watcher.
        $watcher.Dispose()
        # Remove the event job (and with it the event subscription).
        $eventJob | Remove-Job -Force 
      }

    }

  }  


  Write-Host "Starting tasks...`nUse Ctrl-C to stop."

  # Indefinitely wait for and display output from the thread jobs.
  # Use Ctrl+C to stop.
  $dtStart = [datetime]::UtcNow
  while ($true) {

    # Receive thread job output, if any.
    $threadJobs | Receive-Job

    # Sleep a little.
    Write-Host . -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500


  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if you can control apartment state while using thread job. You likely need to rewrite using runspaces directly. Do you have a code with that function containing thread job?

Comment: I'm not quite sure which section of my code you want. I have a Threadjob that has two action blocks, one for Report1Generator and one for Report2Generator. Within Report2Generator it calls a function PicInsertPPT. PicInsertPPT has that code which apparently is not compatible with multi threading.

Comment: Put the code that contains thread job and throws this error, so people can copy, paste and reproduce. Anyway, what you need to do is to replace thread job with custom runspace, and set it's apartment state to be STA.

Comment: There, I added it

Comment: `powershell.exe -sta`